# Sci chart marker re-render issue

Tags: typescript, scichart

We are using a sci-chart in our ReactJs project.

SCI chart values have to be changed from the sidebar and whenever a value is changed from the sidebar the chart values are not updated without re-rendering the entire surface of the SCI chart.  We need to change the sidebar value without re-rendering how is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I don’t really understand the question. If you have annotations on the chart which are updated via the sidebar, then yes the chart will have to be redrawn. However, SciChart carrys out a lot of caching internally to ensure redrawing does not impact performance. Why must the chart not update when you change annotation values? What is the problem with re-rendering? More information required to give a proper answer